# VS2008 navigation bar not showing page controls

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, uinavigationbar, web-controls

In my old job I used to use the navigation bar in visual studio 2008 to select a control and then the event from the members drop-down to automatically create the event in the code for me to implement.  Now at my new job, in my visual studio 2008 I no longer see page controls in the navigation bar.  I only see the page class and associated members.  Does anyone know why it no longer is showing the page controls?

Comment: what you mean by "page controls", maybe custom/user Controls?

Comment: The .net controls created on the aspx page. I am trying to create events for these controls on the code behind.

Comment: Could it be that my new projects are in C#.net rather than VB.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess that it's because you're using C# now instead of VB is correct.

The VB navigation bar shows the Page (or Form or Window if you're working with Windows Forms or WPF) and all of its child controls in the dropdown list on the left side, and all events (whether you're handling them or not) in the dropdown on the right side. You can select an unhandled event to add an event handler.

In C#, the left dropdown contains only the class you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that by navigation bar you mean a control that you got from the toolbox?
3rd party software vendors can add extra controls to the toolbox.
Although I have not experience with asp.net and it's controls, my first guess is that at your previous job you used such a custom control and now at your new job they don't have it installed.

If you really need them a quick [google](http://www.google.be/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=asp.net+controls&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) might help you here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no.  The navigation bar is the top left of the visual studio window which by default displays "Client Objects and Events".  Once you choose an object from the left drop-down, all possible events show up in the right drop-down.

Comment: I see. well I customized my VS to have as much space in the coding window as possible, so I probably (re)moved it. But I see Brian already solved it.